# (PHP) (SQL) What is causing this error?

Tags: php, sql

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET =test WHERE =test' at line 1] in EXECUTE("UPDATE  SET =test WHERE =test")

$sql = 'UPDATE ' . $this->recipientDbTable . ' SET ' . $this->recipientDbColumn['result_id'] . '=' . 'test' . ' WHERE ' . $this->recipientDbColumn . '=' . 'test';
```

Comment: Look at the *actual* SQL string to see why it contains junk. Then stop doing that string concatenation and [use placeholders for the *values*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: Wrong query! Please try to read the error.

Comment: I have bro no clue what's even happening ayy lmao

Comment: `echo $sql` would be a 'start'.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `$this->recipientDbColumn['result_id']` is null or empty. Look at your error log with `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, it may have an Undefined index error.

Also, echo out the actual SQL query and post it here, it should be obvious what the problem is.

Also, use prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks having a look now

Comment: The syntax of the SQL string is incorrect because he's missed an equals sign.

Comment: Echos this over and over UPDATE  SET =test WHERE =testUPDATE  SET =test WHERE =testUPDATE  SET =test WHERE

Comment: `$this->recipientDbTable` is empty and `$this->recipientDbColumn['result_id']` is empty. Figure out whey they're empty.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll accept the answer and go through my code I'm currently writing a new function so a lot of stuff is probably broken haha

Comment: Thanks to the other guys too who posted at the same time

Answer (score 0):

`$this->recipientDbColumn['result_id']` and `$this->recipientDbColumn` as the error suggests return empty string.

> ... right syntax to use near 'SET =test WHERE =test' at line 1] in EXECUTE("UPDATE  SET =test WHERE =test")

As you could see, the call returned empty string. Check the code for where you missed it!

Comment: Thanks having a look now

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, it seems that your `$this->recipientDbTable` & other variables doesn't contains the values.

Try

```
echo $this->recipientDbColumn;
```

Check if it prints the values

Comment: Thanks having a look now

Comment: Yeah it's empty lol looks like I have bigger problems haha, thanks man